# c++ template for std::vector with custom memory allocator

Tags: c++, templates, stdvector

I want to make a template for an argument of a function.

The argument is a `std::vector<type>` with an allocator.

The default is to use the default memory allocator, but custom allocator can also be used.

The following code doesn't work. How to fix this?

```
template <typename T, typename T2=std::allocator<T>>
void pad_zero(std::vector<T,T2> vec, uint32_t n){
    uint32_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        vec.push_back(0);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ad139c309b53f99 ; `=std::allocator<T>` isn't necessary.

Comment: Doesn't work how? Btw it'll change local variable `vec` only.

Comment: both intel c compiler and gcc complains using a <> within template <...>. The problem seems the second template argument  depends on the 1st template argument.

Comment: `>>` is a problem in c++ standards before std c++11. It must be separated by space.

Comment: wow. never knew that. let me try.

Comment: This seems like pretty much an imitation of `std::fill_n`, which you'd use like: `fill_n(back_inserter(vec), n, 0);`

Comment: @JerryCoffin: how to copy n values from an ifstream iterator into the std::vector?

Comment: too bad that the compiler on the computer can't use fill_n...

Comment: @rxu: `std::copy_n` seems like the obvious choice.

Comment: @JerryCoffin That's worse than just using `vec.insert(vec.end(), n, 0)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to provide a default for the allocator. But really the problem is that you're padding a local variable - you accept `vec` by *value*!

Take it by reference, and drop the unnecessary default. Moreover, there's an overload of [`insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) that does exactly what you want, no manual looping necessary (which is not only verbose but inefficient due to the uncertain number of reallocations):

```
template <typename T, typename A>
void pad_zero(std::vector<T,A>& vec, uint32_t n) {
//                           ^^^
    vec.insert(vec.end(), n, T{0});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to provide the allocator, template-argument-deduction will do that for you.

Note additionally that you're passing your vector by value, so inside `pad_zero` you get a **copy** of the vector, whilst the original one remains unchanged, which is probably not what you're looking for

See code below

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5457167a4aeb36db

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename A>
void pad_zero(std::vector<T,A>& vec, uint32_t n)
{
    uint32_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        vec.push_back(0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3 };
    pad_zero(a, 10);

    for (int i : a)
        std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> ```